# Java dom4j scoping xml namespaces instead of keeping them global

Tags: java, xml, merge, dom4j, xbrl

Using the following code that was copied from the internet (by a previous developer - not me)

```
import java.util.ListIterator;
import org.dom4j.Element; 
import org.dom4j.Namespace; 
import org.dom4j.QName; 
import org.dom4j.VisitorSupport;     

class DoNamespaceChange extends VisitorSupport
{
    private Namespace from;
    private Namespace to;

    public DoNamespaceChange(Namespace from, Namespace to) 
    { 
        this.from = from; this.to = to;
    }

    public void visit(Element node) 
    { 
        Namespace ns = node.getNamespace();

        if (ns.getURI().equals(from.getURI())) 
        {    
            QName newQName = new QName(node.getName(), to);    
            node.setQName(newQName);  
        }    

        ListIterator<?> namespaces = node.additionalNamespaces().listIterator();  

        while (namespaces.hasNext()) 
        {    
            Namespace additionalNamespace = (Namespace) namespaces.next();    

            if (additionalNamespace.getURI().equals(from.getURI())) 
            {      
                namespaces.remove();    
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

I am trying to rename XML tags (XBRL actually) attributes during a merge process. The merge process takes 2 XBRL documents and merges them into a single document.

Each pre-merged document is formed with the xmlns tags at the top giving the declarations global scope.

At the top of each document is this header block (or similar)

```
<xbrli:xbrl
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.url.com/" 
  xmlns:ab-CD="http://www.url.co.uk/" 
  xmlns:ef-GH="http://www.url.com/" 
  xmlns:ab-XYZ="http://www.url.com/" 
  xmlns:ur-ACE="http://www.url.co.uk/">
```

Then the relevant sections are listed below this in a nicely human readable format.

**Our merging code currently does not use the Java code above** to edit namespaces but it is going to have use it to to fix a namespace clashing issue between 2 docs having the same **xmlns:url** tags with differing URLs.

In the current world merged documents DO have the headers at the top as shown above.

**However,**

When I run the docs through the code shown at the top, to do the renames, it moves the xmlns tags into the relevant sections themselves (scoping) which I suspect is fine but I would like to know if there is a quick and simple way to rename the tags so that they are merged into a new document. An sample of a merged doc is shown below.

```
<c_xbrli:xbrl
        xmlns:c_xbrli="http://www.url.com"
        xmlns:a_xbrli="http://www.url.com">
    <c_link:schemaRef
            xmlns:c_link="http://www.url.com"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.url.com"
            xlink:href="http://www.url.com"
            xlink:type="simple"></c_link:schemaRef>
    <a_link:schemaRef
            xmlns:a_link="http://www.url.com"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.url.com"
            xlink:href="http://www.url.com"
            xlink:type="simple"></a_link:schemaRef>
```

PLEASE NOTE: This is a work issue so have had to make the data anonymous so please ignore the URL's :)

PLEASE ALSO NOTE: The renamed tags prefixed with a_ and c_ - this is what the renaming code is designed to do so there is no issue here. Simply with the placement in the docs of the  tags

Apologies for this being so long-winded but in a nutshell, all I'd like to know is if it is possible to to preserve any kind of formatting from the original XML docs when passing through dom4j to do renames into the new doc?

or

Why it is doing this to our merged docs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add the namespaces to the root of the document? I don't know dom4j but in other DOMs there is something like a namespace manager for the whole document, where you should add the correct namespaces.

Comment: Thanks Bill,
I got the terminology wrong. Adding the xmlns tags to the root element is exactly what I was trying to ask how to do :) 
I only just discovered this myself by reading and brushing up on XML jargon. I will definitely take a look at this now and see what I can find.